# Javascript memory profiler

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, profiler

I'm looking for a good JavaScript Memory profiler, specifically one that targets IE. And any suggestions on how to go about finding javascript memory leaks would also be appreicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [sIEve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/) ... that's about it. For a while the cardinal answer was Drip, but sIEve is the next iteration by the same guy.

Comment: I just downloaded siEVE. It's nice. Drip on steroids. Thanks!