# Keeping track of javascript memory usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

A web application I am currently working on appears to be leaking memory: with each refresh of a page IE's memory usage goes up and it never releases that memory. Since certain pages are ment to be kept open in a browser and auto-refresh this is quickly turning into a problem.

The application is very javascript-heavy and relies on a combination of old 'plain' javascript code and new JQuery code. I'm looking for tools that would allow me to keep track of the javascript objects and memory allocated but I'm coming up short. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript memory profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663740/javascript-memory-profiler). Should also add the answers to this question to that one, since that question is quite old and not very updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some of the newer versions of [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html?hl=en) you can get a [heap snapshot](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/11/additional-functionality-for-google.html) with the built in developer tools.

When working with IE you can use [DynaTrace Ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) to get a bunch of diagnostics information.

Sorry for the short answer, but I'm not going to [copy pasta](http://wackypedia.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_pasta) what others have written better than me.