# Javascript memory monitor?

Tags: javascript, memory, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663740/javascript-memory-profiler)

I like to know what variables take how much memory in Javascript. Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: Are you asking about in-browser js or server-side like [node.js](http://nodejs.org)?

Comment: @samshull // yes in-borwser javascript

Comment: @Chris Lively: Hard to tell if it is a duplicate. Especially as your linked one asks for IE specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for isn't called "memory monitor". It's called "profiler".

[Javascript memory profiler for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171565/javascript-memory-profiler-for-firefox) e.g. has info for Javascript profilers for running Javascript in Firefox.
Google has lots of profilers for Javascript in various environments: Just search for "profiler javascript"

Answer (score 2):

The webkit inspector in Chrome has a profiler built in that is great for that kind of thing.

As an added bonus it also shows you all browser events such as repaints, so you can engineer your code to have the least impact on the browser.

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028479/finding-memory-leaks-in-javascript-using-firebug/5028545#5028545)

Comment: Than you for your input. It is such a great feature